# How to change listening port on webbserver IIS 7?

Tags: windows, webserver, iis

How do you change the port to which the webbserver IIS 7 is listening for incoming traffic to whatever portnumber?

Comment: Server related questions (such as this one) would find better answers from ServerFault.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click on your site in the left pane, and go to **Edit Bindings**. There you can add and remove ports which are bound to your site (ports it will respond on):

[image]

Comment: Ok, great but can you set it sortof "globally" serverwide and not just sitewide?

Comment: You can set the default website to respond on any port you want which will respond to any requests not handled by other sites, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Allright the thing is that I am tinkering with Apache and would like to have Apache listen to port 80 and IIS to 8080.

Comment: Apache listens on port 80 by default, just change your site to use 8080 in IIS and you're good to go.